# Stop browser (firefox) from updating saved password

Tags: jquery, html, firefox, browser

While developing my user control panel I decided it would be a cool feature to have a `Password Vault`. Here users can share group password and usernames to their work group (in the event they share an account with co-workers) and store their own personal passwords. This also shows the domain it's linked to and the strength of the password.

[image]

Now there is a small issue. When using Firefox, as all great web developers might, when you visit the page it gives you a popup if you click off the page asking you to update the saved user password for the control panel.

[image]

---

I am unsure why as there is no `<form>` anywhere and the fields are not using the same `name, class` or `id`. Here's how a typical field is printed out (note: this is just the `info` field):

```
<div class="pwv_row_column_2">
    <div class="pwv_user">%VAR1%</div>
    <div class="pwv_pass">
        <div class="pwv_eye"></div>
        <div class="pwv_show">
            <input type="password" value="%VAR2%" class="pwv_context" readonly="true">
        </div>
        <div class="pwv_hide">
            <input type="text" value="%VAR2%" class="pwv_context" readonly="true">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And then using the following jQuery I hide and show the password when the `Eye` icon is clicked:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.pwv_eye').click(function() {
        $(this).siblings('.pwv_hide').toggle();
        $(this).siblings('.pwv_show').toggle();
    });
});
```

I have tried using `autocomplete="off"` on the fields, but this does not fix the issue. How can I stop the browser from trying to UPDATE the already saved information? Even tried adding random `name=""` and `id=""` to them to see if that helps: nope.

Comment: the inputs are `readonly`, how is the user changing them?

Comment: the user does not change them, there is an edit button on the far side you cannot see that goes to a different page but no form is being used anywhere on this page. I just used text and password input fields for displaying the current password when its hidden or shown; and to stop people from changing them or erasing them, I have added the `readonly` option.

Comment: Maybe don't use `type="password"`. This is only needed for a form field that the user types into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As dumb as it is, firefox is pre-loading the saved user info into the password fields somehow. The way to stop it was to go at the start of the page and add the following:

```
<div style="display: none;">
    <input style="display: none;" type="text" value="">
    <input style="display: none;" type="password" value="">
</div>
```

And then the page stopped asking to update the saved one.

Comment: His problem isn't auto-filling, the issue is that the browser is offering to save the password change in its password manager.